# How do I resolve the Postgres restore 1 error?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, deployment, pgadmin-4

I have been having issues pushing my database onto Heroku. I have been getting this error:

```
pg_restore: creating DEFAULT "public.user_snacklist id"
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.favorites"
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
 !    pg_restore errored with 1
```

When I run this command

```
heroku pg:push my_database DATABASE_URL
```

where I have my project database replacing "my_database". I have tried deleting my postgres addon and retrying. I have tried editing my database to remove any null data columns. I then retried this method with no luck.

I have a feeling there is something wrong with my favorites table inside my database but my friends and I could not find anything useful.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like corruption in the archive or could be version mismatch. Where was pg_dump taken and version used? What version of pg_restore is being used?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am new to programming so I don't know. I never used or commanded pg_dump or pg_restore